# Converting raw pixel data to QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qimage, qpixmap, raw-data

I'm trying to convert raw pixel data to QPixmap but there is an error while converting qimage to qpixmap.

First, I send raw data from server A by qlocalsocket and Client B gets it.

This is Server A.

```
    if (clientSocket)
    {
        if (clientSocket->isOpen())
        {
            QByteArray block;
            QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

            out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_7);
            const char* rc_data = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(r_data);
            out <<sizeof(strlen(rc_data))<< r_width << r_height << r_step;
            out.writeBytes(rc_data, strlen(rc_data));

            clientSocket->write(block);
            clientSocket->flush();
        }
    }
```

This is Client B.

```
    QByteArray block = connection->readAll();
    QDataStream in(&block, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_7); 
    char* data;
    size_t size;
    int width;
    int height;
    int step;
    while (!in.atEnd())
    {
        in >> size >> width >> height >> step;
        in.readBytes(data,size);
    }
    mutex.lock();
    receivePixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(QImage((unsigned char*)data, width, height, step, QImage::Format::Format_RGB888));
    mutex.unlock();
    ui.label->setPixmap(receivePixmap.scaled(ui.label->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
}
```

There is no error converting (unsigned char*)data to QImage but error while QPixmap::fromImage.

When I debug the code, sended and received data are same.

This is my error.
Error : 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDD1.

And occurs at here.

```
    #ifdef Q_COMPILER_RVALUE_REFS

    static QPixmap fromImage(QImage &&image, Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags = Qt::AutoColor)
        {
    return fromImageInPlace(image, flags);
    }
    #endif
```

Please share your idea thanks.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: i updated it.
Error : 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDD1.

Comment: Are you sure all the data is available when the code in your client snippet is executed? Add some checks in your code. Check how many bytes are available, and check if `data` is `null` and the value of `size` after `in.readBytes`. The second parameter of `QDataStream::readBytes` is not the size to read, it is used to get the size of the buffer.

Comment: i tried like this, **out.writeBytes(rc_data, sizeof(strlen(rc_data))); in.readBytes(data, size); ?? //size is sizeof(strlen(rc_data))//** but when i use like that, i can read just 4bytes of rc_data. because the sizeof(strlen) is 4bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this problem

```
    writeBytes(rc_data,r_step*r_height)
    readBytes(data,r_step*r_height)
```

I checked strlen(rc_data), but this size is not correct.

Actual size of image was step*height.

thank you guys~~~!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you serialize, you write the size component as `sizeof strlen(rc_data)`, i.e. `sizeof (size_t)`, which is likely much smaller than the content of `data` (it's often 4 or 8 bytes).  When you reconstruct the image data, you only read that size, so the `QImage` now refers to memory space that's not as big as it needs to be to represent `width`x`height` pixels.

You need to write the actual length of `data` in order to read it back successfully.  `strlen(rcdata)` is almost certainly the wrong measure, as it measures null-terminated strings, which your pixel data is not.  Without a complete example, it's not possible to tell how you should determine the length of `rc_data`.

Comment: you mean that i have to use like these?

**out.writeBytes(rc_data, sizeof(strlen(rc_data)));**
**in.readBytes(data, size);** ?? //size is sizeof(strlen(rc_data))

but when i use like that, i can read just 4bytes of rc_data. because the sizeof(strlen) is 4bytes..

Comment: `rcdata` needs to contain `width * height * bytes_per_pixel` bytes, so you should be able to calculate it if you know those three numbers.  Since you are passing `QImage::Format::Format_RGB888`, you know `bytes_per_pixel` is 3.

Answer (score 0):

Use QPixmap's loadFromData method:

```
bool QPixmap::loadFromData(const uchar * data, uint len, const char * format = 0, Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags = Qt::AutoColor)
```

Or

```
bool QPixmap::loadFromData(const QByteArray & data, const char * format = 0, Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags = Qt::AutoColor)
```

More info: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#loadFromData

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem (that most of the referenced data have never been read).